# Phone call service providers cost checket

Tags: c#, interview-questions

The question:

> You have many phone calling service providers. They each have a prices and special deals for many phone numbers.
>
> Design an algorithm and a data structure to support the function, given a phone number give the best available price for all of the given providers in the atabase.
>
> For example:
>
> Service provider Parter has a price of 20 cents for all of the numbers which start with +15.... however for +1507... the price is 70 cents.
>
> Service provier Verizon has a price of 30 cents for al the numbers which start with +15...
>
> The best price for the number 150741799 should be 0.3 from Verizon.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{


    [TestClass]
    public class BestCallingPriceTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetBestPriceTest()
        {
            string givenPhoneNumber = "150741799";
            CallCenter callCenter = new CallCenter();
            double bestPrice = callCenter.GetBestPrice(givenPhoneNumber);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.3, bestPrice);
        }
    }

    public class CallCenter
    {
        private readonly PricesTrie _pricesTrie;
        public CallCenter()
        {
            _pricesTrie = new PricesTrie();
        }

        public double GetBestPrice(string givenPhoneNumber)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(givenPhoneNumber) || _pricesTrie.Head == null)
            {
                return Double.MaxValue;
            }
            Dictionary<string, double> tempCompanyPrice = new Dictionary<string, double>();

            var phoneCharArray = givenPhoneNumber.ToCharArray();
            var currNode = _pricesTrie.Head.Edges[phoneCharArray[0]];
            for (int i = 1; i < phoneCharArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (currNode.IsTreminal)
                {
                    foreach (var company2Price in currNode.Company2PriceMap)
                    {
                        //there is already a price for this company you need to update it to the new value
                        if (tempCompanyPrice.ContainsKey(company2Price.Key))
                        {

                            tempCompanyPrice[company2Price.Key] = company2Price.Value;

                        }
                        else // there is no price for this company
                        {
                            tempCompanyPrice.Add(company2Price.Key, company2Price.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (currNode.Edges.ContainsKey(phoneCharArray[i]))
                {
                    currNode = currNode.Edges[phoneCharArray[i]];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return tempCompanyPrice.Values.Min();
        }
    }

    public class PricesTrie
    {
        public TrieNode Head { get; set; }

        public PricesTrie()
        {
            Head = new TrieNode();
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            Head.Edges.Add('1', new TrieNode());
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges.Add('5', new TrieNode());
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].IsTreminal = true;
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].Company2PriceMap = new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {"Partner", 0.2},
                {"Verizon", 0.3}
            };
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].Edges.Add('0', new TrieNode());
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].Edges['0'].Edges.Add('7', new TrieNode());
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].Edges['0'].Edges['7'].Company2PriceMap = new Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                {"Partner", 0.7}
            };
            Head.Edges['1'].Edges['5'].Edges['0'].Edges['7'].IsTreminal = true;
        }
    }

    public class TrieNode
    {
        public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> Edges { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, double> Company2PriceMap { get; set; }
        public bool IsTreminal { get; set; }

        public TrieNode()
        {
            Edges = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
            Company2PriceMap = null;
            IsTreminal = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it simple with a basic structure under the assumption that the data is stored in a flat format.

```
public class Rate {
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

`Provider` could just as easily been a foreign key from the provider table.

Calculating the best price was done by selecting the rates that match the prefix, grouping them by provider, ordering by longest matching prefix and taking the best price from the first sub-group

```
public class CallCenter {

    public Rate GetBestPrice(string givenPhoneNumber) {
        var available = getRates()
            .Where(r => givenPhoneNumber.StartsWith(r.Prefix))
            .GroupBy(r => r.Provider)
            .Select(g => g
                    .GroupBy(r2 => r2.Prefix.Length)
                    .OrderByDescending(g2 => g2.Key)
                    .First()
                    .OrderBy(r => r.Price)
                    .First()
            );

        return available.OrderBy(r => r.Price).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Rate> getRates() {
        var rates = new List<Rate>() {
            new Rate{ Provider = "Parter", Prefix = "15", Price = 0.2M },
            new Rate{ Provider = "Parter", Prefix = "1507", Price = 0.7M },
            new Rate{ Provider = "Verizon", Prefix = "15", Price = 0.3M },
        };
        return rates;
    }
}
```

And here is the test for completeness

```
[TestClass]
public class BestCallingPriceTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetBestPriceTest() {
        //Arrange
        var givenPhoneNumber = "150741799";
        var expectedPrice = 0.3M;
        var expectedProvider = "Verizon";
        var callCenter = new CallCenter();

        //Act
        var actual = callCenter.GetBestPrice(givenPhoneNumber);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedPrice, actual.Price);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedProvider, actual.Provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a Trie is the best solution for this problem. If we are talking about search complexity.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the answer, although I think you answer is ok. I think it is a simple version. you are given here with a choice for every data structure and algorithm you can think of, this is not a C# question per say. so although you use LINQ which is great, what happens when you need to implement it in other programming language. in the new c++11 you can implement this but in the old c++ I find it hard to implement. Also like Gilad said performance wise Trie is the best solution the interviewer said so to me also.

Comment: @InterviewsAreUs I just put it as an option given that the question was tagged with c#. This is what came to mind for me. Agree that is probably not the most efficient. Different ways to do the same thing I guess.